# How to append DateTime list to CSV without comma separated delimiters?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, datetime, delimiter

I could use some help here. I am attempting to append a DateTime Index that I have converted to a list to an existing CSV file. When I run the code the list does append as intended but the times are comma separated whereas the list being used to append the data is not. My code is below

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd

time_now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
time_future = time_now + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)
time_predict = pd.date_range(time_now, time_future, freq = '5min')
time_predict_list = time_predict.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").tolist()

overwrite = input("Would You like to Overwrite or Append Prediction Data? Type (a) to Append, Type (o) to Overwrite: ")
if overwrite == "o":
    np.savetxt("time_list.csv",
               time_predict_list,
               delimiter =", ",
               fmt ='% s')

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
        csv_writer.writerows(list_of_elem)

if overwrite != "o":
    append_list_as_row('time_list.csv',time_predict_list)
```

Actual output:

```
2021-02-08 10:54:31
2021-02-08 10:59:31
2021-02-08 11:04:31
2021-02-08 11:09:31
2021-02-08 11:14:31
2021-02-08 11:19:31
2021-02-08 11:24:31
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,0,:,5,4,:,5,1
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,0,:,5,9,:,5,1
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,1,:,0,4,:,5,1
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,1,:,0,9,:,5,1
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,1,:,1,4,:,5,1
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,1,:,1,9,:,5,1
2,0,2,1,-,0,2,-,0,8, ,1,1,:,2,4,:,5,1
```

Then intended output would be the same values in rows 8-14 but without being separated by commas

Comment: `writerow` not `writerows`.  The latter takes a list of lists, not a list.  Strings are iterable and look like a list of single characters.

Answer (score 1):

`writerows` is incorrect.  It requires a list of lists.  A list of strings looks like a list of lists because strings are iterables of characters.

Use `writerow`, but to put each item on a separate line each "row" needs to be a list of the items in the row.  In this case, that is a single item:

```
for row in list_of_elem:
    csv_writer.writerow([row])
```

You don't really need the `csv` module when you can open the file in the mode you want.  Pass an opened file to `np.savetext`:

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    with open(file_name, 'a') as file:
        for row in list_of_elem:
            print(row,file=file)

time_now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
time_future = time_now + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)
time_predict = pd.date_range(time_now, time_future, freq = '5min')
time_predict_list = time_predict.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").tolist()

overwrite = input("Would You like to Overwrite or Append Prediction Data? Type (a) to Append, Type (o) to Overwrite: ")

with open('time_list.csv', 'w' if overwrite == 'o' else 'a') as file:
    np.savetxt(file, time_predict_list, fmt='%s')
```